# Using DLLs Qt - Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I am trying to use and make a DLL in Qt. The DLL, **does not** use any Qt frameworks. Here is my library's .pro file:

```
TARGET = MyLib
TEMPLATE = lib

include(Botan.pri)
win32:INCLUDEPATH += "C:/botan/include"
win32:LIBS += "C:/botan/libBotan.a"

unix:INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/include/botan-1.10"
unix:LIBS += "/usr/local/lib/libbotan-1.10.a"

HEADERS += \
    HEADERS HERE

SOURCES += \
    SOUCRES HERE
```

My library is compiled successfully, and I get a MyLib.dll in my debug/release folder. I then copied my library sources completely, and removed everything besides the header files for the 'includes' folder.

I then created a new project to use my library.

I added this to my project file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Users/Stevie/Desktop/MyLib/include"
LIBS += "C:/Users/Stevie/Desktop/MyLib/MyLib.dll"
```

The headers have no problem, and it finds my DLL fine (if I change it to a non-existing path, it throw an error. It doesn't as of now.)

Now when I go into my '.cpp' file, I include my header file, and try and use my library and it throws 'undefined reference to `MyLib::`...'. I have no idea why, as I am including the DLL and I believe it should be found perfectly fine.

Also, I am 99% sure it isn't with Botan, as I use Botan often like this, and it works fine. Anyway, I include the 'Botan.dll' with it anyway just to be sure, but it's not throwing the undefined errors on Botan.

Thanks.

Comment: `LIBS += "C:/Users/Stevie/Desktop/MyLib/MyLib.dll"` looks a bit suspicious, as normally on Windows you are supposed to use .lib files at link time, and .dll files at runtime.  At least, this is the case when using MSVC, but you may be using MinGW... I'm not sure if things are different there.  Do you have a MyLib.lib ?

Comment: I  am using the MinGW to compile. The weird thing is, is that this does work with Botan.

Answer (score 0):

Replace
LIBS += "C:/Users/Stevie/Desktop/MyLib/MyLib.dll" 
with 
LIBS += -L$$quote(C:/Users/Stevie/Desktop/MyLib)
LIBS += -l$$quote(MyLib)

Does your library have Q_DECL_EXPORT / Q_DECL_IMPORT macros?

After all that clean and rebuild your project, which use library.

Comment: No, I do not use any macros. What are these/are these needed? Also, this did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Macro is defined in <library_name>_global.h <br>
Par example: <br>
#ifndef LIBPFT3_GLOBAL_H <br>
#define LIBPFT3_GLOBAL_H <br>

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h> <br>

#if defined(LIBPFT3_LIBRARY) <br>
#  define LIBPFT3SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT <br>
#else <br>
#  define LIBPFT3SHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT <br>
#endif <br>

#endif // PFT3LIBDEVEL_GLOBAL_H <br>

Then you need to insert LIBPFT3SHARED_EXPORT in all definitions of your classes and global static functions:<br>

like this:<br>

class LIBPFT3SHARED_EXPORT PFT3DataFF : {<br>
    public:<br>
};<br>